# My array of structs is printing out garbage

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I am writing a program that takes in an input file using file i/o and stores the data in the file into arrays of structs. Keep in mind that I'm providing you parts of my code. Not the whole thing. I know for a fact that everything is working fine, because I'm printing out all the arrays of structs once I input the data. The garbage that is printing happens in the function before I attempt to sort it. That function, in which I attempt to sort it, is called in my read file function, in which I printed the array of structs. There, it printed perfectly. When it calls the sort function, the array of structs prints out garbage.

---

This is an example of an input file that I have been using:

```
### building room_number capacity 
SAL 210 30 
OHE 100 120 
OHE 120 50

### ID prefix course# sect# #minutes #mtgsperweek #students 
20001 CSCI 101 01 110 2 40 
20002 CSCI 101 02 110 2 60 
20003 CSCI 101 03 110 2 100 
20004 CSCI 103 01 90 2 50 
20005 CSCI 103 02 90 2 50 
20006 CSCI 103 03 90 2 75 
20007 CSCI 104 01 80 2 50 
20008 CSCI 104 02 80 2 50 
20009 CSCI 109 01 90 1 25 
20010 CSCI 109 02 90 1 25
20011 CSCI 109 03 90 1 25 
20012 CSCI 109 04 90 1 25 

### ID days_constraint start_constraint end_constraint 
20001 MW 1000 1400 
20002 MW 1000 1400 
20003 TR 1000 1400 
20004 TR 0800 1200
20005 TR 0800 1200 
20006 TR 0800 1200 
20007 MW 0800 1200 
20008 MW 0800 1200 
20009 M 0800 1200 
20010 M 0800 1200 
20011 T 0800 1200 
20012 T 0800 1200
```

---

I have a function in which I read the file and input the data into the arrays of structs using stringstream. I know that part of the program is correct because I am afterwards printing out the arrays of structs, and they all print out perfectly. The issue comes up when I call a new function, inside my read_File function, called sort_ByClassroomSize, in which I am trying to sort the arrays of structs in descending order by classroom capacity.

---

Here is the struct:

```
 struct Room { 
   char building_code[4]; 
   int room_number; 
   int max_students; 
 };
```

I declare a pointer and later dynamically allocate depending on the number of rooms the user entered.

```
         struct Room* roomsPtr;

         roomsPtr = new struct Room[room_size];
```

Where room_size is a counter the counts the number of lines that declare a room.

Here is how I input the data into the struct:

```
   if( !(line[0] == '-' && line[1] == '-') ) {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << line;
        ss >> roomsPtr[i].building_code;
        ss >> roomsPtr[i].room_number;
        ss >> roomsPtr[i].max_students;
        if( ss.fail() ) {   //checks format; terminates program if incorrect.
        cout << "The file has been formatted incorrectly." << endl;
        return;
        }

        //prints lines in section 1.
        cout << roomsPtr[i].building_code << " " << roomsPtr[i].room_number << 
            " " << roomsPtr[i].max_students << endl;
```

---

The problem is going wrong in the sorting function:

```
    void order_ClassroomsBySize(int num_rooms) { //arranges classrooms in descending order 
    by classroom size
         struct Room temp_value;

              //prints the array of structs before arrangement
        cout << endl;
            cout << "Arranged classrooms in descending order by classroom size: " << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < num_rooms; i++) {
           cout << roomsPtr[i].building_code << " " << roomsPtr[i].room_number << " " 
            << roomsPtr[i].max_students;
           cout << endl;
        }
    } 
        //arranges the array of structs in descending order by classroom size
        for(int i = 0; i < num_rooms; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < num_rooms - 1; j++) {
                if(roomsPtr[j].max_students < roomsPtr[j+1].max_students) {
                  temp_value = roomsPtr[j];
                  roomsPtr[j] = roomsPtr[j+1];
                  roomsPtr[j+1] = temp_value;
                }
           }
        } 

        //prints the array of structs after arrangement
        cout << endl;
            cout << "Arranged classrooms in descending order by classroom size: " << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < num_rooms; i++) {
           cout << roomsPtr[i].building_code << " " << roomsPtr[i].room_number << " " 
            << roomsPtr[i].max_students;
           cout << endl;
        }
    }
```

---

My program is printing out the following:

```
### building room_number capacity 
SAL 210 30 
OHE 100 120 
OHE 120 50


### ID prefix course# sect# #minutes #mtgsperweek #students 
20001 CSCI 101 01 110 2 40 
20002 CSCI 101 02 110 2 60 
20003 CSCI 101 03 110 2 100 
20004 CSCI 103 01 90 2 50 
20005 CSCI 103 02 90 2 50 
20006 CSCI 103 03 90 2 75 
20007 CSCI 104 01 80 2 50 
20008 CSCI 104 02 80 2 50 
20009 CSCI 109 01 90 1 25 
20010 CSCI 109 02 90 1 25
20011 CSCI 109 03 90 1 25 
20012 CSCI 109 04 90 1 25 

### ID days_constraint start_contsraint end_constraint 
20001 MW 1000 1400 
20002 MW 1000 1400 
20003 TR 1000 1400 
20004 TR 0800 1200
20005 TR 0800 1200 
20006 TR 0800 1200 
20007 MW 0800 1200 
20008 MW 0800 1200 
20009 M 0800 1200 
20010 M 0800 1200 
20011 T 0800 1200 
20012 T 0800 1200

Arranged classrooms in descending order by classroom size:
course# sect# #minutes OHE 593851250 1667592992
t# #minutes OHE 1970170221 544433524
OHE 120 50

Arranged classrooms in descending order by classroom size:
course# sect# #minutes OHE 593851250 1667592992
t# #minutes OHE 1970170221 544433524
OHE 120 50
```

Comment: Why not use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) for the sorting? And of course [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for strings. Using the facilities in the [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) will help you in the long run as a C++ programmer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am new to c++. I have not learned vectors yet! This is the third program I have written. I have not reached classes either. I just finished learning structs and pointers.

Comment: I hate to disappoint you, but you're likely to be learning about structures and pointers for a few years yet.  Also, structures are classes with all members public (and probably no explicit member functions).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's not the point. The point is that I have not learned vectors. I'm taking an introduction to programming class at USC. And, I want to use the concepts I have already learned in class so that I can understand them and practice with them.

Comment: For the moment this is only C in disguise, and not really C++. Are you sure that your teacher wants to teach you C++, or is it merely C? These are two different languages.

Comment: @JensGustedt: this is a common way of introducing C++ in classrooms. (I don't agree with it either, but it's how it works)

Comment: My point was not that you should be using vectors et al (though a modern approach to teaching C++ would teach vectors et al from the start).  My point is that even though you may have finished the module(s) of the course on pointers and structures, you will still be learning more about both pointers and structures over the next few years.

Comment: We are in fact learning c++. Classes is our next topic.

Comment: This is what we have learned: 
Compilers,
Basics of C++,
Structure of a program,
Variables and types,
Constants,
Operators,
Basic Input/Output,

Program structure,
Control Structures,
Functions,
Overloads and templates,
Name visibility,

Compound data types,
Arrays,
Character sequences,
Pointers,
Dynamic Memory, Structures

Comment: I have no programming experience prior to this course. I did not know C before taking the class. The class is the first class computer science majors take at USC. So, it assumes you have no knowledge of programming.

Comment: Can you check, at the beginning of your sort function, what the roomsPtr array contains? Your sort function appears to work find when I hard coded in values.

Comment: It contains the following:                                           SAL 210 30,      
                                                                         OHE 100 120, 
                                                                        OHE 120 50. I am comparing the last part, the numbers (30, 120, and 50), and I'm trying to arrange the rooms so that the the rooms' capacities are in descending order. We can see that roomsPtr contains these values because I printed them out earlier, and they printed correctly.

Comment: @Khaelid Actually, the array contains garbage as well, before I sort it! I wonder why that is? It prints correct when I print out the arrays earlier.

Comment: should I pass in the ptr?

Comment: @RafaelVergnaud If the pointer is global (which isn't good practice, but should work) then you shouldn't need to pass it in. Does this line `roomsPtr = new struct Room[room_size];` happen before or after the block where you input the rooms?

Comment: It happens before the block where I input the rooms.

Comment: Are you incrementing `i` in your input loop?

Comment: I am! That all seems to be working fine. Because I print out the data right after, and it prints out well. It's only when I call the function within the input file function that the garbage comes out.

Comment: Can you attach the entire source file?

Comment: Yea, I think that would be easiest! How do I do that?

Comment: I meant just copy and paste it like the other code in your question. You can't actually attach files on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but part of the problem may be these lines:

```
cout << "Arranged classrooms in descending order by classroom size: " << endl;
for (std::set<Room>::iterator i = rooms.begin(); i != rooms.end(); i++)
{
    cout << i->building_code << " " << i->room_number << " " 
        << i->max_students;
       cout << endl;

}
```

In particular:

```
    cout << i->building_code << " " << i->room_number << " " 
        << i->max_students;
```

By writing `cout << i->building_code`, you're telling `cout` to print out whatever is in that `char` array, namely, `i->building_code`. But `cout` doesn't know how big the array is, so it keeps printing out stuff it sees until it reaches a null character (`char a = 0`). This causes `cout` to go way past the boundary for your character array in printing stuff.

The way to fix this might be to make `i->building_code` a 5-byte array instead of a 4-byte array, and zero the array out before populating the struct:

```
for (int j = 0; j < num_rooms; j++)
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        roomPtr[j]->building_code[i] = 0;
```

See this page about [C-strings](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/66-c-style-strings/) (character arrays terminated with a null byte) for more information.

Also, this code segment:

```
    //arranges the array of structs in descending order by classroom size
    for(int i = 0; i < num_rooms; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < num_rooms - 1; j++) {
            if(roomsPtr[j].max_students < roomsPtr[j+1].max_students) {
              temp_value = roomsPtr[j];
              roomsPtr[j] = roomsPtr[j+1];
              roomsPtr[j+1] = temp_value;
            }
       }
    }
```

Should look like this:

```
   for(int i = 0; i < num_rooms - 1; i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < num_rooms; j++) {
            if(roomsPtr[i].max_students < roomsPtr[j].max_students) {
              temp_value = roomsPtr[i];
              roomsPtr[i] = roomsPtr[j];
              roomsPtr[j] = temp_value;
            }
       }
    }
```

If you're going for the [Selection Sort Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) (like I think you are).

Answer (score 1):

Like many have commented, you're using two very different paradigms in your code: You're using C++ as if it were C. There's just much easier ways to do this if you really are using C++.

Idiomatically, I would simply use operator overloading if I was in C++.

Like this:

```
class Room {
    // not generally a good idea to have public members, but if you must...
    public:
        std::string building_code;
        int room_number;
        int max_students;
        bool operator == (const Room & other) {
            if (max_students != other.max_students)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else return room_number == other.room_number && building_code == other.building_code;
        }
        bool operator < (const Room & other) {
            // returning the oposite to ensure descending order.
            return max_students > other.max_students;
        }

 };
```

Then, you could just put your `Room` objects in a `std::set`, which both dynamically allocates enough memory for all the rooms you need, *and* keeps them sorted in descending order, like this:

```
#include <set>

std::set<Room> rooms;
room.insert( /* populate a room and put it here */);
room.insert( /* populate a room and put it here */);
```

So that you could just output them like this:

```
cout << "Arranged classrooms in descending order by classroom size: " << endl;
for (std::set<Room>::iterator i = rooms.begin(); i != rooms.end(); i++)
{
    cout << i->building_code << " " << i->room_number << " " 
        << i->max_students;
       cout << endl;

}
```

Everything I learned about C++, I probably learned it from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/).

Comment: I appreciate the answer! However, I mentioned before that I have not learned classes yet. Classes will be our next topic after the midterm. I would like to use concepts that I already know and with which I can practice. I should not be using classes for this programming assignment, because we have not learned classes. I really appreciate the answer, however!